# php foreach loop only outputs last array key value

Tags: php, loops, random, foreach, while-loop

I have some code to generate 4 unique random numbers between 0-9: -

```
//Globals
$arr = array();
$gridMax = 9;
$i = 0;


while ( count($arr) < 4 ) {
$x = mt_rand(0, $gridMax);
    if ( !in_array($x, $arr) ) {
        $arr[] = $x;

        }
}

print_r($arr);
```

I'm trying to create a grid and if the corresponding grid number is the same as one of the 4 unique values in my array then I want it to add some text to the $build variable. If not, do nothing: -

```
while ($i <= $gridMax) {
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if ($value == $i) { 
        $build = "build";
    } else {
        $build = "";
    }

}

echo "<li class=\"map\">{$build}</li>";
$i++;
}
```

However, it only works for the final value in the last key (shown here): -

http://www.kryptonite-dove.com/sandbox/mt_rand/

Can anyone give me some pointers? I've been absent from coding for a number of months and my mind is a little foggy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($i <= $gridMax) 
{
    $build = '';
    if(in_array($i, $arr)) $build = 'build';

    echo "<li class=\"map\">{$build}</li>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: This seems a lot faster, easier on the eye and more efficient so have marked as the answer. Thanks very much all.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
while ($i <= $gridMax) 
{
    $build = '';

    foreach ($arr as $value) 
    {
        if ($value == $i) 
        { 
            $build .= "build";
        }   
        else        
        {
            $build .= "";
        }
    }

    echo "<li class=\"map\">{$build}</li>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm thanks! can you explain why it works like this for me?

Comment: I know, I know! Let's say $i = 3, $arr = [1,2,3,4]. In your original code for 1 and 2 it's false, for 3 the $build changes to 'build', but for 4 it changes again to ''. Here you append to $build instead of setting it.